# Media center app that is designed to use with a mouse, not with tv and remote control

Tags: windows, media-manager, metadata

Media Centers like Plex and Kodi are extremely uncomfortable to use with a mouse, they all are oriented to run on a big tv, with those giant posters and as little data on the screen as possible.

I'd like to find some desktop application without touch- or remote-oriented interface that can run in the windowed mode, feels quick, has metadata scraping, can launch files in external media players, maybe even with webdav and other network data support.

I like Plex web interface, but don't like using web player there. Or think something iTunes-ish or like Steam. Maybe some metadata managers or collection managers can do this?